Advantages of elastic net with relatively small sample sizeh?
I'm conducting Elastic Net (EN) regression with a sample size of 75 and 140 variables (features). I used cv.glmnet to set the optimal lambda, and then performed Elastic Net (EN) regression using glmnet. Here's my some questions

I am planning to select features that appear in at least 3500 out of 5000 iterations (70%). Is there any justification for using 70% or 80% as the cutoff during iterations? At the moment, it seems to be a heuristic method without a clear basis.

Aside from the fact that Elastic Net provides coefficients, are there other advantages to using Elastic Net with my data? When I plot the correlations, about 90% of the variables show significant correlations (p<0.05), and approximately 30% have r>0.5, indicating multicollinearity.

I am performing classification, regression, and prediction using Elastic Net. For initial feature selection and comparision with using all 140 features, I selected those with p < 0.05 in univariate linear regression (for regression) and choosing variables significant to moderate effects (p < 0.1) in ANCOVA with 4 covariates (for classification). Since this is just a process for selecting variables, do I need to use FDR-corrected p-values, especially in the case of ANCOVA?


